# Is there a general way to prevent overflows when summing lists?

Tags: haskell, sum

I'm working with ByteStrings, and by extension a lot of Word8.
When i write `sum word8List`, the returned value is also Word8, but i know my data, and that sum is too large for a Word8. Should i avoid sum, or does it work differently than i think?

Is there some general function for summing numbers without overflowing, like `Num a => a -> Integer`?

Comment: Just first map it to a larger type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sum will use the `(+)` defined for that type, so for a `Word8`, it will make a wraparound.

You can however first perform a mapping, for example with [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral), and thus convert the numbers to another numeric type (like `Integer`, `Word16`, `Word32`, etc.). For example:

```
sum (map fromIntegral word8List) :: Integer
```